# What analytic functions have relatively large absolute values on the unit disc?

Tags: complex-analysis

Yesterday I consulted MSE since I wanted to find all functions f which are analytic on the open unit disc, continous on the closed dito, and which in addition have the following two properties:

(1) The absolute value of f is 1 on the unit circle.

(2) The absolute value of f(z) is strictly larger than the absolute value of z to the power of 2019 on the open unit disc.

At first I thought that all functions of the form z^n where n is an integer between 0 and 2018 would have these properties, but someone pointed out that a problem arises at the point z=0. Having lost 2018 functions instantly I found myself left with only the constant function f(z) = z^0 = 1. However another person informed me that I had actually infinitely many functions at my disposal, namely all constant functions f(z)=a, where the absolute value of a is 1.

The latter person considered elegantly the function 1/f and concluded that the absolute value of f can't be  neither strictly larger nor strictly smaller than 1 anywhere on the closed unit disc. When thinking about his argument I realised that we can probably put something else in the numerator if we want to as long as it's a constant not equal to 0. For example it would work equally well, I believe, to consider the function i/f.

Furthermore it struck me that the talk about [z]^2019 in the formulation of the problem is probably just a cumbersome way of saying that f has no zero inside the unit circle. Another way of saying the same thing could be that the absolute value of f is strictly larger than the absolute value of g on the open unit disc, where g is an unspecified function whos absolute value is strictly smaller that 1 everywhere (to avoid a contradiction). As far as I can see we don't need to know the exact value of g at any point.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: $1$ implies $f$ finite Blaschke product while $2$ implies that only zeroes can be at $0$ though it doesn't hold with strictly at $0$ unless $f$ constant

Comment: $f$ has no zero so $1/f$ is analytic as well and fulfills the same condition, so the maximum modulus principle gives that both $|f|$ and $|1/f |$ are $\le 1$ on the closed disk. This implies that $f$ is constant (of modulus $1$).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Reuns. This sounds like an argument that I can understand.  Perhaps the talk about [z]^2019 in the formulation of the problem is just a roundabout way of saying that the function has no zero inside the unit circle. Everything else seems to follow from the first property. Am I right?

Comment: Is that word spelled with two ts i English?  How is it used? I used it and spelled it the way it's spelled and used in Swedish since I thought that the usage and the spelling are probably the same in both languages.